# How to add SEO related terms in the page to maximize seo rank for certain keywords?

Tags: seo, keywords, ecommerce

We have platform where users can sell their bikes. The most relevant SEO key terms user type to find online platform to sell the bike is like:

1. Sell bike in new york
2. Sell bike in new jersey (Similar keywords in other popular cities)
3. Sell my old bike
4. Sell my bike
5. Sell bike

We have created a landing page for letting the user upload their bike on our platform to sell. We have placed images for these popular cities and below the city image, we have written the city name.

The problem is Google is only able to see "new york", "new jersey" below the city image by this and not "sell bike in new york", "sell bike in new jersey" etc. And placing text like "sell bike in new york" etc. below each image would be very bad user experience.

How can I change image text to be more SEO friendly? And how should the text of this page be modified to gain best SEO rank if we want to target above 5 key searches?

Comment: I guess you could actually put "Sell Bike in New York", then use the placement of the image so that it actually covers the "Sell Bike in" part. Just an idea though. Also, there is the images `alt` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

To me, it appears more to do with website planning and less to do with image etc what you have said.

Now, where you got an image with link and text under the image etc, doesn't matter you can place it however you like and look at the problem in more holistic way.

**How to target Service with Location?**

- As stated above make your website structure proper.
- Lets say your website is: example.com
- You can create category pages based on locations like:
- example.com/service-name-in-location
- And try and optimise the location page with appropriate text, images, videos etc.

Note:

- User pages will be a temporary, so your prime focus should be to optimise home and category pages.

With regards to image, make sure you have ALT tag. And appropriate description depending on the space you may have.

Comment: example.com/service-name-in-location.. problem is we have multiple location.. but currently pages for all location looks exactly same.. except that city dropdown would come pre filled. I am worried that Google may treat it as duplicate.. although I will put common canonical for all..

Comment: You should create different URL for different location category. You need to look at your website structure. If not implemented correctly you may have a major impact.

Comment: Would different url for different cities with exactly same content except city comes prefilled in the page..this would be treated as duplicate content and penalized?

Comment: Yes, If you got different URL but almost similar content then yes it will be treated as duplicate content. So, if you are planning to create different pages for the different city then take time and build unique pages and then load. Similar content won't help at all.